# PInescript V5 stock data in array and export in other script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

is it possible in a library file to store values in a string type array and to be able to retrieve them in another script with the import function

example:

```
mylibrairie 

Array string data = (string1, string2 etc....)

export myData(data)
// create cell tab
```

Answer (score 0):

To export a string array you need to declare the array inside the exported function.

Library:

```
library('String',true)

export Data() =>
    string[] Data = array.from('Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3')
```

Indicator:

```
import String/1 as st

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, close, st.Data().get(0))
```